# Get index of element when using broadcasting using function dot notation in Julia

Tags: julia

if i have the following example function

```
function isBigger(element)
   if element > 3
       println("element bigger than three")
   end
end
```

and i call it on `a=[1 5 7 2]` with `isBigger.(a)`.
I get:

```
>bigger than three
>bigger than three
```

What can i do to get the indices of the elements?
I'd like to get

```
>Element at index 2 is bigger than three
>Element at index 3 is bigger than three
```

It should also still possible to call the function on a single value like `isBigger(4)`:

```
isBigger(4)
>bigger than three
```

Comment: "It should also still possible to call the function on a single value" - what would the output be then? `Element at index ??? is bigger than three`?

Comment: When you broadcast, `isBigger` only gets the element, not its index. That's it.

Comment: The logic of the function is slightly different, I would create two functions, one for array elemets as argument and one for scalars .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a typical job for broadcasting because you want to keep track of the indices. So, a normal loop over the elements is the correct choice here. Now, because your function has two distinct logics, as @Antonello pointed out, you're better off using Julia's multiple-dispatch machinery. Create a small function for scalars and a more restricted function for arrays.

```
isBigger(n) = n > 3 && println("Bigger than 3") 

isBigger(a::AbstractArray) = begin
    for i in eachindex(a)
        a[i] > 3 && println("Element at $i is bigger than 3") 
    end
end
```

Which works as follows:

```
a = [1, 5, 7, 2]
isBigger(a)
 Element at 2 is bigger than 3
 Element at 3 is bigger than 3

isBigger(4)
 Bigger than 3
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `findall` function

```
julia> a=[1,5,7,2];
julia> findall(x->x>3, a)
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 3
```

You can also combine this with your function

```
function isBigger(element)
   if element > 3
       println("element bigger than three")
       return true
   else
       return false
   end
end

findall(isBigger, a)
```